# $A=\{(3x,y)\mid x,y\in \mathbb Z\}$ is a maximal ideal of $\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

I've a question from gallian which states:

Show that $A=\{(3x,y)\mid x,y\in \mathbb Z\}$ is a maximal ideal of $\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z$.Generalize.What happens if $3x$ is replaced by $4x$...

can anyone explain me the strategy to show it is a maximal ideal (*I just know the basic definition of maximal ideal)*...

thanks in advance for any help..

Comment: Can you describe the quotient $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} / A$?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi maybe I'm not sure :  $(3x+w,y+z)$ $w,z \in \mathbb Z$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B$ be an ideal such that $A$ is a proper subset of $B$. We show that $B$ is the full ring.

Let $(s,t)$ be in $B$ but not in $A$. Then $3$ does not divide $s$. Note that $(s,0)$ is in $B$ but not in $A$. The remainder when we divide $s$ by $3$ is $1$ or $2$. Or, better, $s$ is congruent to $1$ or $-1$ modulo $3$.

If the remainder is $1$, then $s=1+3q$ for some $q$, so $(1,0)$ is in $B$, and therefore $(w,y)$ is in $B$ for every $w$ and $y$, meaning that $B$ is the whole ring.

A similar argument deals with the case $s$ congruent to $-1$ nodulo $3$. Or just work with $-s$.

In general, the set of all $(px,y)$, where $p$ is prime, is a maximal ideal. The set of pairs $(4x,y)$ is not, since the set of pairs $(2x,y)$ is a larger proper ideal.

**Remarks:** $1.$ For proving the result for all primes, one can use the fact that if $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime, then there exist integers $u$ and $v$ such that $au+bv=1$.

$2.$ Soon you will have more conceptual tools to deal with such problems.

Comment: I can't understand 1 thing that why did we only put restriction on $s$ in $(s,t)$ and not on $t$...Kindly help..

Comment: Because the description of the ideal $A$ as the set of ordered pairs $(3x,y)$ lets the second coordinate roam absolutely freely. Since $(0,z)$ is in the ideal for any $z$, we have $(u,z)\in A$ (respectively $B$) if and only if $(u,0)\in A$ (respectively $B$).

Comment: You are welcome. It is important to have things be clear. Soon, or maybe already, you will see that the quotient structure $(\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z)/A$ is isomorphic to the **field** of $3$ elements, and therefore the ideal is maximal.